# Why won't ternary operators work in KDE holiday files?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I recently switched to Linux and am trying to customize the calendar.  Most of it is simple enough, but there are a few days which are conditionally found.  For instance, one holiday I'm adding is normally the 2nd Sunday after January 1st.  But if it falls on the 14th or 15th, it moves to the previous Monday instead.  Here's what I have (actually all on one line):

```
white "Feast of the Baptism of the Lord" on 
    ([sunday after 9.1] == [14.1] ? [8.1] : 
     [sunday after 9.1] == [15.1] ? [9.1] : [sunday after 9.1])
```

According to what I've seen online, this should work.  But instead it not only doesn't add the day to the calendar, but kills parsing of the file and prevents anything after it from being added either.

Comment: Which calendar utility are you talking about?

Comment: There's a scripting language for describing holidays.  It's based on PLAN, but the KDE team has added a few features.  It's KOrganizer's Holiday File Format.  [link](http://community.kde.org/KDE_PIM/KOrganizer/Holiday_File_Format)